# How to verify if an element with a class appears using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I need to verify with this div appears, but it's not working. I'm trying to use by classeName.

```
<div aria-live="polite" class="ui-growl-item-container ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-growl-message-sucess">
```

My Code:

```
const validacao =  element(by.className('.ui-growl-item-container.ui-state-highlight.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow.ui-growl-message-sucess'));

expect (validacao.isPresente()).ToBeTruthy();
```

Protactor keeps returning me false.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're passing CSS selector, but not class name.

To make it work as expected, try

```
const validacao =  element(by.css('.ui-growl-item-container.ui-state-highlight.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow.ui-growl-message-sucess'));
```

or

```
const validacao =  $('.ui-growl-item-container.ui-state-highlight.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow.ui-growl-message-sucess');
```

or you can pass single class name to `by.className()` as

```
const validacao =  element(by.className('ui-growl-item-container'));
```